# Python: How to find text of first anchor tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML structure like this

```
<p class="title">
  <a href="abc.com">
   Story
  </a> 
  <span class="domain">
    <a href="xyz.com">comments</a>
  </span>
</p>
```

I want to extract text of first anchor tag, that is `Story`

Here is how I am using `Beautifulsoup` to extract text from anchor tag

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
for link in soup.find_all(class_='title'):
      print link.findNext('a').text
```

and output:

```
Story

Comments
```

But I want to extract only text of first anchor tag, that is `Story`.
How can I do this using BeautifulSoup in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the first `a` tag by doing

```
print link.a.text
```

To strip the extra whitespace

```
link.a.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by *chaining* the `find()` calls and using `get_text()` method:

```
soup.find("p", class_="title").a.get_text(strip=True)
```

where `.a` is equivalent to `.find("a")` in `BeautifulSoup`.

Or, with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select_one("p.title > a").get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: i got this error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar then, the HTML is different from what you presented.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the text of the first anchor, then you don't need `find` using the class.

You didn't say anything about the `class="title"`.

```
In [9]: html = """
<p class="title">
  <a href="abc.com">
   Story
  </a>
  <span class="domain">
    <a href="xyz.com">comments</a>
  </span>
</p>
"""
In [10]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
In [11]: soup.a.text.strip()
Out[11]: u'Story'
```

Comment: suppose above html structure is repeated multiple time then how can i find first anchor tag in all tag whose class is 'title'

Comment: My answer will always find the very first anchor tag regardless of any classes. If you want the first anchor within some element with a class, see the other answers